# How to optimize CRUD operation in EF using DBContext?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a function which grabs the data from API and stores into the database.

```
public async Task GetApps()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps?per_page=200");
            var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            AppsClass.AppsRootobject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppsClass.AppsRootobject>(json);
            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContexts>();

                foreach (var item in model.resources)
                {
                    var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
                    var x = _DBcontext.Apps.FirstOrDefault(o => o.AppGuid == g);

                    if (x == null)
                    {
                        _DBcontext.Apps.Add(new Apps
                        {
                            AppGuid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                            Name = item.name,
                            State = item.state,
                            CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                            UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                            SpaceGuid = Guid.Parse(item.relationships.space.data.guid),
                            Foundation = 2,
                            Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                        });
                    }

                    else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                    {
                        x.State = item.state;
                        x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                        x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                        x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                    }

                    var guids = model.resources.Select(r => Guid.Parse(r.guid));
                    var apps = _DBcontext.Apps.Where(o => guids.Contains(o.AppGuid) == false && o.Foundation == 2);
                    foreach (var app in apps)
                    {
                        app.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }

                await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

The above function works just fine except the snippet for `DeletedAt`

```
var guids = model.resources.Select(r => Guid.Parse(r.guid));
                    var apps = _DBcontext.Apps.Where(o => guids.Contains(o.AppGuid) == false && o.Foundation == 2);
                    foreach (var app in apps)
                    {
                        app.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    }
```

it's not like it doesn't work at all but when the `GetApps` function called every second because of this snippet I'm getting the following error

> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for
>   context type 'TestApp.Context.DBContexts'.
>         System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This
>   may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max
>   pool size was reached.

If I remove `DeletedAt` snippet it works just fine but I need that functionality, is there any way to optimize this? can I make it async?

Comment: A DataTime object cannot be null.  So you can use the default 1/1/1 by using new DateTime().  Any validate will not be 1/1/1.

Comment: @jdweng its not the issue I kept it there by mistake the issue is still  there

Comment: Changing a property on your `app`s causes each affected `app` to be marked as changed (assuming you're using object proxies). When you need to update the `app`s, the total run time of GetApps() is longer than the interval at which you call that method, so you eventually run out of DbContext from the pool. How many apps are updated?

Comment: around 1200 for now but they will grow in future

Comment: How long does the query take in Sql Server Management Server?  Is the database SQL Express?  Yo may actually be exceeding the default max time of 30 seconds.  When you do not have DeleteAt the query is not performing x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at so it runs quicker.

Comment: I have not run delete query in SSMS but rest of the insertion doesn't take more than 3 ms.

Comment: its SQL Server not SQL Express

Comment: it will run `x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at` when there are any updates in data it works really well the only problem is the `deleted_at` snippet